# Java FX Textarea performance issue in .jar

Tags: performance, jar, javafx, textarea

I have a TextArea that I would like to be able to append characters or words to over a period of time. I use Timer from java.util and when I run application in Eclipse everthing works ok, but when I export application into .jar I have performance issue.

Here is video from Eclipse:
http://pl.tinypic.com/r/4ftw1f/8

Here is .jar:
http://pl.tinypic.com/r/6zmoon/8

And code:

```
@FXML
private TextArea textarea;


public void start(KeyEvent keyEvent)
{
    if (keyEvent.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER)
    {
        new Timer().schedule(
                new TimerTask() {
                    int i;
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        textarea.appendText("hey" + i + "\n");
                        i++;
                    }
                }, 0, 500);

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you reproduce it after computer restart?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has threading issues: in Java 8 it will just throw `IllegalStateException`s as you are trying to update the UI from a background thread. You need

```
        if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER)
        {
            new Timer().schedule(
                    new TimerTask() {
                        int i;
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            String message = "hey"+i+"\n";
                            Platform.runLater(() -> textArea.appendText(message));
                            i++;
                        }
                    }, 0, 500);

        }
```

I don't know if that will fix your performance issue or not. Appending text to a text area essentially involves doing lots of string concatenation; eventually (as the text in the text area gets long) this is going to be prohibitive. You might want to use a virtualized control (such as `ListView`), depending on the functionality you need.